# CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'product_profile.price' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I get this error when I run `Product.php` that is model file and I get this error

> CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 
>   Unknown column 'product_profile.price' in 'where clause'. The SQL statement executed was: 
>   SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `product` `t` INNER JOIN product ON product_profile.product_id = 
>   t.product_id WHERE product_profile.price >=0 AND product_profile.price <=100

The code of query is below

```
if (!empty($_POST['price'])) {
    $price = explode(",", $_POST['price']);
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select = 'product_profile.price,product_profile.product_id';
    $criteria->join.='INNER JOIN product ON product_profile.product_id = t.product_id';
    $criteria->condition = " product_profile.price BETWEEN 1 AND 100";
    // $criteria->condition = 'product_profile.price >=0 AND product_profile.price <=100';
    $criteria->addInCondition("product_profile.price",$price);
}
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: @Gumbo you where quicker on this code ;)

Answer (score 3):

You are joining `product` with `product` table and hence `product_profile` is not found

The correct sql should be

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM product t 
INNER JOIN product_profile  ON product_profile.product_id = t.product_id 
WHERE 
product_profile.price >=0 AND product_profile.price <=100
```

So the following

```
$criteria->join.='INNER JOIN product ON product_profile.product_id = t.product_id';
```

should be

```
$criteria->join.='INNER JOIN product_profile ON product_profile.product_id = t.product_id';
```

Answer (score 0):

You need change your SQL syntax via Yii ORM. Your finally query should be like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product t 
INNER JOIN product_profile
ON product_profile.product_id = t.product_id 
WHERE product_profile.price >=0 AND product_profile.price <=100
```

It means thant you need to JOIN product_profile table, not product table

Comment: thanku all i get ride from this error but its not showing me any product of this price range

Answer (score 0):

And if other columns finded, but one - not.
Here is code.

```
$pages = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('*')
            ->from('sk_subj_img_links')
            ->where('subj_clas=:subj', array(':subj'=>'math-1'))
            ->queryAll();
```

Then I get error: CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'subj_clas' in 'where clause'
But if this code

```
$pages = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('*')
            ->from('sk_subj_img_links')
            ->where('id=:tid', array(':tid'=>’1'))
            ->queryAll();
```

- then works write
  Columns of table sk_subj_img_links: id, link, subj-clas.
  When find link column – also works.